# PHP SOAP get different results when using variables

Tags: php, soap

I need to get data by calling function B from one SOAP service. Before i calling function B, i need to call function A from the same SOAP service.

The result from function A is a string: $result and $result = 'ojfwooslsl'; Then i should pass the $result to function B. The strange thing is that, when i pass the variable $result to function B, the result from function B is wrong. When i pass 'ojfwooslsl' to function B, the result is right. Anyone know what is the difference? thanks very much. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$option=array('trace'=>1);
$client = new SoapClient("http://ws.jrtwebservices.com/jrtlowfaresearch/jrtlfs.asmx?WSDL",$option);

$result=$client->do_LowfareSearch(array('rq'=>$array));// return the token
$token= $result->do_LowfareSearchResult;
var_dump($token); //string(32) "36fd9751e9cb480493f0e70f529d79f7" 
    $response= $client->do_Polling(array('rid'=>$token));
$results= $response->do_PollingResult;
```

?>

When  $response= $client->do_Polling(array('rid'=>"36fd9751e9cb480493f0e70f529d79f7")); it works. when  $response= $client->do_Polling(array('rid'=>$token)); it does not.

Comment: Show code; show dump of the SOAP string passed to the function using both methods.

Comment: @DigitalChris i updated my question. the dump results are same.

Comment: Assuming this is where the problem lies, there must SOMETHING different about them: `var_dump(array('rid'=>$token))` and `var_dump(array('rid'=>"36fd9751e9cb480493f0e70f529d79f7"))` and compare

Comment: @DigitalChris the var_dump results are same: array(1) { ["rid"]=> string(32) "d14016eb288b421aa4af181d1a041cee" } array(1) { ["rid"]=> string(32) "36fd9751e9cb480493f0e70f529d79f7" }. because the token results are different every time, so the var_dump values are different. It is very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. i found the problem. because the SOAP server needs time to produce the results, so i can not use the variable immediately. It works when i delay 14 seconds.

Comment: I would not rely on a specific time of seconds, minutes, whatever when the server is doing something asynchron. you can never be sure that the progress is completed after exactly 14 seconds.

Comment: I would request every e.g. 500ms, 1second, 2seconds or something else (don't know how much the average duration of the server takes to complete to prepare the data) if the server already got the data. if you got the data, break. otherwise do it so long until you get the expected data. but i would not try as long as you get data. could be that the server is not responding. so break after 30 seconds (or something else) when you got no data.